# How to write text file data into same cell of excel using bash

Tags: excel, bash, shell

I have a scenario where I want to redirect all the output of a text file into a single cell of excel.

text file data:

```
"remove dead code" 
"keep cassandra and postgres in OR condition"
"InsertFailCDRList"
"to be updated in error handling US, write TODO here in comments"
```

I want this data in my one column.
For eg.

```
    C1             C2
    1            TEXT FILE OUTPUT HERE
    2            OTHER TEXT FILE OUTPUT HERE
```

But problem is text is not coming single cell but it spreads to multiple cells.

Using commands:

```
#!/bin/bash  -x
output=$(cat commentmessage.txt)
number=1
echo $number,"${output}" > buc_review_comments_data3.csv
```

Output is like:

```
        C1             C2
         1            "remove dead code"
        "keep cassandra and postgres in OR coniditon"
        "InsterFailCDRList"
```

I want all under row 1 column 2. How can we do this using bash? Please help.

Desired Output:

```
       C1                C2
        1            "remove dead code"
                     "keep cassandra and postgres in OR coniditon"
                      "InsterFailCDRList"

        2             "new data here"
                      "new data"
```

[image: Format required - this is result wanted]

So Basically, I have 
ID=BUC123

totalcomments=4

Text file - containing multiple comments.

Want these in above format in excel.

Comment: **A side note:** In  `echo $number,"${output}"`, the comma is just used to separate the arguments passed to `echo` and won't appear in the csv file.

Comment: comma actually seperates columns in my csv. number goes to row1 column1 while output goes to row1 column2 which is fine.

Comment: All I need is text file with multiple lines to be available as single value in same cell i.e. row1 column2.

Comment: When importing, do tick the `Use " as separator` box

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop to iterate over the contents of your input file, and then prefix each line with your number:

```
#!/bin/bash
infile=commentmessage.txt
outfile=buc_review_comments_data3.csv
number=1

while read line
do
    echo "$number","$line"
done < "$infile" > "$outfile"
```

Let me add a few hints:

- Curly braces are mainly useful to separate variable names from other characters that are allowed in variable names inside double quotes, e.g.: `"${myvar}otherstuff"`. But they can also enhance readability of your code. In your example, you could do `echo "$number,$line"` as well (because `,` is not allowed in variable names), but `echo "${number},${line}` would be nice and clear about what your variable names are, while saving the separate quoting.
- While it is not necessary to quote `$number` in your example, as a best-practice, [you should always double-quote your variable expansions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).
- If you just read from a file, use redirection (`<`) instead of `cat`, see [Useless Use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: Don't forget to increment `n` :)

Comment: @Michael Jaros _Thanks for your response Michael. But this gives me my infile data in different cells (different rows). What I want is my $number in row1 column1 and my infile data all multiple lines in single cell i.e. row1 column2. it should not go in mutiple cells of excel sheet._

Comment: I added the image to show exact output format required.

Comment: @user3256114 OK I see, but according to your question, the data the comments should be grouped by (obviously "ID") is not in your input file. Could you clarify?

Comment: @fzd: It was not really clear how that number should be calculated. According to the last change, it is not an increment but the number of comments per ID.

Comment: @Michael Jaros Yes, basically for testing I just used number instead of ID. Its constant anyways. I want to have those 4 comments in single cell against a constant ID. I was just using number as that constant in my test script.